# Returning a pointer to a struct using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to return a pointer to a new struct I've created but I get a segmentation fault and am unsure how to do this the correct way.

This is what I'm using right now:

```
 typedef struct person{
  int age;
  char *name;
 }Person;

 Person *new_person(int age, const char *name){
  Person *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
  x->age = age;
  strcpy(x->name, name);
  return x;
 }
```

I've been tweaking with this code from tutorials/other questions I've found online. But I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, whether it's the way I allocate the memory or the way I return the pointer.

Another issue I have is deallocating any associates memory with a certain Person. Say I wanted to remove a person, and deallocate any dynamically associated memory with that person. I searched it and it said I should to use the `free` method. But I still get a memory leak with it. I have something set-up like this:

```
void kill_person(Person *x){
    free(x->name);
    free(x);
}
```

Should I be calling `free(*x)`? And should I also be calling `free(x->name)`?

Comment: You should call `free(x->name);` before calling `free(x);`, assuming you use a separate allocation to allocate `x->name` in the first place.  For each `malloc()` in your code, there should be a matching `free()`.  (Using `realloc()` slightly complicates things, but the basic concept remains valid — for each allocation that is not already freed, you should be able to point to the matching `free()`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I updated op to what I'm using, but I'm still getting a memory leak and not deallocating properly

Comment: There are endless ways of getting a leak and we won't be able to guess what you've done. Is [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) available to you?  If so, use it (but compile the code with `-g` to get better reports on where the leaks occur). If you can't get `valgrind`, you'll have to produce an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea — into an update (not overwrite) of the question. But use `valgrind` if you can.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm sort of confused from what you're saying. What I'm working on is an assignment, and I know I'm getting a memory leak from running the tests I was supplied with. The tests run my methods and checks to see if I deallocated the memory properly after running the methods. (so I know that the issue is in one of those methods)

Comment: I'm saying that there are a lot of different ways to create leaks, and without seeing all the allocation and deallocation code, we can't possibly guess which method of leaking you're using.  It's unfortunate, but also a fact of life.  You shouldn't show us all your code here.  But if you create an MCVE that still leaks, you could show that.  But it would be better to learn `valgrind` which directly tells you where you leaked memory.

Comment: For a program I was playing with earlier today, with the `free()`'s commented out, `valgrind` tells me: `==23078== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 21 of 88`
`==23078==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)`
`==23078==    by 0x19EEAA: strdup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)`
`==23078==    by 0x100000DD5: main (c3d.c:34)`
`==23078== LEAK SUMMARY:`
`==23078==    definitely lost: 240 bytes in 12 blocks`
`==23078==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`
`==23078==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`. It tells me the line where the memory was allocated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry for the bombardment of questions, but I'm not sure I understand you still. That's all my deallocation code, and I've changed my allocation code to the provided examples below.  I don't see why there shouldn't be a straight answer to the memory leak, since I know it's a problem with one of those methods. But i'll look into valgrind. thanks

Comment: It isn't all your deallocation code; it is just the only function where you call `free()`.  The rest of the deallocation code is where you make arrangements to call the function.  And you need to show the allocation code, and where the allocation code is called, because that's the other half of the issue.  Without both allocation and deallocation code (the calls to `malloc()` and `free()`, plus the code that calls the functions containing that code), we cannot tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for Person as well as it's pointer within i.e name. Othertwise, evenif Person gets allocated it's name portion will remain unallocated.

Option 1:

```
typedef struct person{
  int age;
  char *name;
 }Person;

Person *new_person(int age, const char *name){
  Person *x = (Person *) malloc(sizeof(Person));
  if (name != NULL) {
      x->name = (char *) malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
  }
  x->age = age;
  strcpy(x->name, name);
  return x;
 }
void kill_person(Person *x){
    free(x->name);
    free(x);
}
int main() {
  Person *p = new_person(28, "Neel Lohit");
  // code to use p, when done, call kill_person
  kill_person(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Option 2 (name portion having fixed static allocation):

```
#define MAX_SZ 100
typedef struct person{
  int age;
  char name[MAX_SZ+1];
 }Person;

Person *new_person(int age, const char *name){
  Person *x = (Person *) malloc(sizeof(Person));
  x->age = age;
  strcpy(x->name, name);
  return x;
 }
void kill_person(Person *x){
    free(x);
}
int main() {
  Person *p = new_person(28, "Neel Lohit");
  // code to use p, when done, call kill_person
  kill_person(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the two different examples! I updated OP with one more question on deallocation, if you could point me in the right direction

Comment: You need to check that each allocation works before blithely using the result.  In the first code, if `name == NULL`, the `strcpy()` will probably crash (it invokes undefined behaviour, and the usual response to this particular undefined behaviour is usually a crash).  In the later code, you should arguably ensure that `name` is not longer than `MAX_SZ`.

Comment: @Mark, updated my answer regarding deallocations, accept ans?

Answer (score 2):

```
Person *x = malloc(sizeof(x));
```

You meant to write

```
Person *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
```

---

`sizeof x == sizeof(Person*)`, so you only allocated enough memory for a pointer.  You're next segfault will (probably) be on this line:

```
strcpy(x->name, name);
```

You never allocated `x->name`.  A proper function would be:

```
Person *new_person(int age, const char *name) {
    Person *x = malloc(sizeof *x);
    x->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    x->age = age;
    strcpy(x->name, name);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, the post I was learning off of never allocated memory for the name, so I assumed it was unnecessary. I updated OP with another question for deallocation if you could point me in the right direction that'd be most helpful

Comment: Wow for some reason that posted here, trying to fix

Comment: @Ed S. Is it necessary to allocate memory for `x->name` also..? Instead of , Can we try like `x->name= name` (assigning the string address without `const` in arguments). Is it possible.?

Comment: Person *x = malloc(sizeof(*x))  will allocate memory for pointer to Person, not the Person itself. Doesn't op wants to allocate for Person?

Comment: @RavichandraSutrave: No, it won't.  It will allocate `sizeof *x` bytes, which is `sizeof Person`.  You have it backward.